# ASP.NET Login Control checking multiple databases before logging in

Tags: asp.net-membership

I have 2 databases that have users in them.  The databases allow for an easy seperation of data that can be used across one web system.  I have asp members on each database and I am trying to set up the login control to check the frist database and if the first database has the corresponding username/password then log the user in, if not I need the login control to check the second database to see if the user is in that database with the correct credentials.  I am not sure how to swich the login control to look at another database, is there any prebuilt metodology to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not the login control that checks the database...

One way to go is implementing your own Custom Membership Provider.

http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider

Another way is to go if you don't need a full membership provider is to issue an authentication cookie after verifying the correct credentials yourself